# Find the pattern sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to help my grandchild with $6$th grade math homework.  The question given is:

$$ 3.5,\ \      13,\ \      41.5,\ \     127, \cdots $$

What are the next $3$ numbers?

Comment: $*3+2.5{}{}$...

Comment: To counteract the $.5$'s, double all terms first.  Then find out whether there is a "rough" ratio that is common between successive terms.  Finally, given an approximate ratio that looks good, see if a "nice" ratio with an offset creates the series.

Comment: Or if you suspect the relation between terms satisfies $a_{i+1} = ma_i+c$, maybe you should try to solve for $m$ and $c$, and use the extra number to confirm.

Comment: Is this normal 6th grade middle school math?

Comment: This sort of question ("recognizing a pattern") has been discussed and generally accepted to be not acceptable for this site. One reason is because there's no reason to assume that any sequence of numbers has a pattern, and even if it does there's no reason the pattern is what a human would naively expect it to be. There's a pattern in the sequence 1, 1, 2, 8, ..., don't you see it? It's obvious, it's the number of primitive sorting networks on $n$ elements, and the next number is 62.

Comment: This is "normal" only if the pattern is relatively easy to spot (which in this case, it sort-of was)

Comment: Also, you may find that occasionally random special cases of advanced topics show up in grade school math education. I was tutoring someone in math and they had taught them how to compute the number of elements in the union of three sets if you know the sizes of their intersections. This is called the principle of inclusion-exclusion, and I didn't know anything about it until I took combinatorics in grad school.

Comment: I gave a Grade 10 student a brief excursion into limits when division by zero came up. I was always dissatisfied myself with with $x/0$ being undefined. So I told him, "We can't divide by zero, but what we *can* do is look at the graph of $y=3/x$ and talk about what happens as $x$ approaches $0$ from either side. I don't think he caught on. But later I showed him what happens when you put any number into a calculator and hit "cos" a couple dozen times. His eyes widened. I think *that* one he'll show off. And, yes, we did discuss a little of what was happening there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that the teacher probably *wants* is given in the comments. Through inspection, it appears that the teacher expects the student to notice that each term is generated by multiplying the previous term by $3$ and then adding $2.5$. But as also noted in the comments, there are are more complex patterns that fit this sequence, and could result in a different answer.

Another possibility, if your grandchild is feeling brave, is to show the following graph, and offer an explanation:

"I conjectured that these were measurements taken at some regular interval. So I plotted their base ten logarithms and extrapolated. It appears that that the next measurement would be $~10^{2.6}$ which is about $398$."

Sadly, this response may merit your grandchild a D in Math 6, but an A in Physics 11.

(BTW, the response the teacher may want for the next number is $383.5$, so this is pretty close, but to be fair, my graph seems to hit the point closer to $2.7$. We're largely having some fun here, which is what math is *for*, right?

It would be fun to see how close this extrapolation brings us two the next two numbers.)

[image: logs]